# Embed  Facebook wall from a page onto an external website

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

We have a Facebook page for our company. We want to embed the wall for our company onto our website. How would you go about doing this?

The worst case would be an iframe for the whole page, but I was hoping just to get the wall.

Comment: What may I ask is the marketing & sales value in embedding a company's Facebook page on their website; and would you prefer to have this embedded page be your website home page, or have a tab for it? Not meaning to be a smart aleck here, simply want to understand the motivations/ intentions better. All answers welcome

Comment: I know this is old, but for people finding this question I would like to note that embedding the whole page in an iframe doesn't work - FB blocks that usage.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you can use Facebook's "[Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)" social plugin.

Take the following steps:

1. Paste the URL of your Facebook page into the box with caption "Facebook Page URL"
   -> You will immediately see how the plugin will look for your page
2. Click on "Get Code"
3. Paste the iframe or XFBML code into your webpage.

Answer (score 3):

There is no pre-baked solution yet to embed a Facebook wall in a website as far as I know. I am researching the same issue.

It seems possible by using Graph API. I found [this blog post](http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2953-How-to-Embed-Facebook-Wall-Content-on-Any-Site) detailing the steps to do it. The first step is getting a permanent access_token, which is best explained in Facebook Docs - Google "facebook api authentication" to find it - (it somehow didn't work when I was using the blog instructions).

You obtain the content of the feed, but without Facebook's UI (no Like, Comment, etc). It's the best I've found.

Alternatively, if you're using Wordpress there is a plugin allowing to embed any Facebook object in your website with all the Facebook fanciness. It's called "[Embed Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embed-facebook/)"

Sorry I couldn't post more than 2 links in this post.

Answer (score 2):

You can go here and use the FaceBook live stream API

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/#

If you sign up for a facebook `app_id` then there is a form on that page, which, when filled in will give you the code to embed the live stream on any website.

Comment: This answer needs some more detail to add value - at first glance at the facebook documentation is verbose but doesn't give clear steps. Answers here in webapps should serve to explain.

Comment: And which "live stream" ? It seems that exposing wall/status updates from a facebook *page* is not as obvious as from a facebook  user.

Comment: Seems like the live stream plugin referred above has been deprecated by Facebook. 

According to Facebook: "The Live Stream Plugin has been deprecated and will be removed on October 3, 2012. Please migrate to use the Comments Plugin instead." 

The comments plugin however does not seem to enable embedding facebook wall content into an external site.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an elegant alternative you might want to look at an app like Postano. It allows you to aggregate multiple social media channels (eg Twitter, Facebook, Instagram) into a visually pleasing feed on your company's page. Here's a link if you want to check it out: http://www.postano.com/solutions/for-websites/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default Like box, or rolling something yourself using the Graph API, an alternative is to use a product like [Tint to embed your facebook wall](http://www.tintup.com). It's an easy tool that can embed and display any social feed on any website. To use it, you connect your accounts and it generates an embed code.

You can also use Tint to aggregate from Twitter accounts/hashtags, Instagram accounts/hashtags, and Youtube Channels into one page and easily embed it anywhere like any website, FB page tab, etc.

It has a number of really nice themes and personalization options so your content can shine.

Examples: [Tint Clients](http://www.tintup.com/clients)